# No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined

Tags: xml, spring, spring-security

When configs are loaded, I get the error

SEVERE: Exception starting filter springSecurityFilterChain
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined

My sec-config:

```
<http use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/error/casfailed.html" entry-point-ref="headerAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll"/>
    <!-- <intercept-url pattern="/index.html" access="permitAll"/> -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/index.html" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/history.html" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/absence.html" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/search.html" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/employees.html" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/employee.html" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/contract.html" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/myforms.html" access="hasAnyRole('HLO','OPISK')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/vacationmsg.html" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/redirect.jsp" filters="none" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/error/**" filters="none" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/layout/**" filters="none" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/js/**" filters="none" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />

    <!-- session-management invalid-session-url="/absence.html"/ -->
    <!-- logout logout-success-url="/logout.html"/ -->
    <custom-filter ref="ssoHeaderAuthenticationFilter" before="CAS_FILTER"/> <!-- CAS_FILTER ??? -->
</http>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="doNothingAuthenticationProvider"/>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="doNothingAuthenticationProvider" class="com.nixu.security.sso.web.DoNothingAuthenticationProvider"/>
<beans:bean id="ssoHeaderAuthenticationFilter" class="com.nixu.security.sso.web.HeaderAuthenticationFilter">
<beans:property name="groups">
    <beans:map>
      <beans:entry key="cn=lake,ou=confluence,dc=utu,dc=fi" value="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    </beans:map>
</beans:property>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="headerAuthenticationEntryPoint"
            class="com.nixu.security.sso.web.HeaderAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>
```

And web.xml

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
     /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
     /WEB-INF/sec-config.xml
     /WEB-INF/idm-config.xml
     /WEB-INF/ldap-config.xml
    </param-value>
  </context-param>

<display-name>KeyCard</display-name>


<context-param>
<param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
<param-value>KeyCardAppRoot</param-value>
</context-param>


  <context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.properties</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <!-- Reads request input using UTF-8 encoding -->
  <filter>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>encoding</param-name>
      <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

 <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
  </listener>


  <listener>  <!-- this is for session scoped objects -->
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <!-- Handles all requests into the application -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>KeyCard</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>tiles</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.tiles.web.startup.TilesServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>
        org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG
      </param-name>
      <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/tilesViewContext.xml
      </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>KeyCard</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>
      120
    </session-timeout>
  </session-config>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <!-- error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/WEB-INF/error/error.jsp</location>
  </error-page -->

</web-app>
```

What's wrong?

Comment: I am not getting your web.xml config. Its not clear in your question.

Comment: Sorry, those formats seem not to work here.

Comment: do you have spring security jars in run time environment?

Comment: How did you solve the problem. Could you paste all your configuration files.

Comment: Comment on one of the answers reveal that this was a tiles definition problem, but no details.

Answer (score 3):

maybe, you're missing bean loader.

**application-context.xml**

```
<beans:import resource="webmvc-context.xml"/>
<beans:import resource="webflow-context.xml"/>
<beans:import resource="security-context.xml"/>
```

**web.xml**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/application-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Answer (score 0):

are following configurations present in your web.xml?

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Actually, the fault was wrong tiles definition! I so not did except that, because I didn't get any errors involving tiles!

Comment: @michael can you please explain what a wrong tiles definition is?

Comment: Yes, please @michaeljackson4ever - this will help to eliminate my problem as well

Comment: I'm also having the same issue, and would be great if op could clarify what he/she meant by wrong title.

Answer (score 0):

Just for future users. It seems that the name of the filter is case sensitive and can not be changed.

See [this thread](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/100875-no-bean-named-springsecurityfilterchain-is-defined) in spring forum. I still have problems but at least I know that the name of the filter is more than just a reference between the filter and the filter-mapping.